# bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation

I'm trying to install a GUI for Dansguardian (https://bitbucket.org/ssoulaimane/webcontentcontrol-gambas3) but when I type:

`./configure && make && sudo make install`

I get an error message:

`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

I have completed all the previous steps mentioned in the manual (on the site I provided), unless I have misunderstood something.

Comment: What directory are you in when you issue the command? What **are** the contents of the directory (using `ls`)?

Comment: I'm in my home directory. Should I be in the directory where dansguardian and the other programs are installed? It's installed to /usr/sbin. Oh and to make things clearer, I'm trying to install a GUI for Dansguardian and the other two programs.

Comment: You should be in the directory into which you cloned the git repository of the source package you are trying to build: if you cloned into your home directory that will probably be `~/webcontentcontrol-gambas3` - unless you specified an alternate directory on the `git` command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first clone the repository (use `git clone https://bitbucket.org/ssoulaimane/webcontentcontrol-gambas3`).

After that you should change directory the repository folder using `cd webcontentcontrol-gambas3` and only after that you should do `./configure && make && sudo make install`.

`configure` is a file located in that repository and it's written in `bash`. You don't have any file named `configure` in your home folder so that's why you have to `cd` on your repository folder.

By the way, if the command `./configure && make && sudo make install` listed above doesn't work use `bash configure && make && sudo make install`. But I really doubt it won't.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! Thanks for the info, now I have enough info to do some research on the subject on my own :)